# facebook image fetch problem

Tags: image, facebook

i added an addthis button to this website:

http://www.merchzilla.com/shop/php/products.php?id=148&SHOP=webshop

now i've got a problem with sharing the site's images with facebook. doesn't work with the addthis button, neither by pasting the link into a wall post.

i wonder why, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it with a metatag to share a specific image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{ImageURl}" />
```

seems that facebook needs absolute image urls to fetch an image from your website

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, all my sites use this line of code in the `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="site-meta-image.png" />
```

I have never included an absolute image url and they all work absolutely fine with Facebook.

Comment: hmm, maybe the problem was that it was a relative url "../../site-meta-image.png" ?